# Need to assign custom taxonomy to the pages with specific php template - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

I created in Wordpress custom taxonomy called 'consultants_category' and assigned it to custom post type. Now I need to assign this taxonomy to pages with specific php template - 'page-consultants.php'.

Wordpress have function to assign custom taxonomy called 'register_taxonomy_for_object_type' (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy_for_object_type/) but when I use it - my taxonomy (custom categories) are shown on the backend of all wp pages and I don't know how to take pages only with specific page template.

Here is rough idea of what I need to achive (get all wp pages -> filter all pages to get pages only with specific php template -> assign custom taxonomy only to filtered pages ):

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
$pages = get_pages(
     array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-consultants.php'
       )
);

foreach($pages as $page){
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'consultants_category', 'pages');
}
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Developer by `saeed Hanif`

To assign a custom taxonomy to pages in WordPress and display those pages using a specific template, you can follow these steps:

###### Create a custom taxonomy:

In your theme's functions.php file, use the `register_taxonomy()` function to create a custom taxonomy. For example:

```php
function create_page_taxonomy() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Page Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Page Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Page Types' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Page Types' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Page Type' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page Type:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Page Type' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Page Type' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Page Type' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Page Type Name' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Page Types' ),
  );

  $args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'page-type' ),
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'page_type', array( 'page' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_page_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Add the code to display the pages with the custom taxonomy in the body of the template file:

```
$page_type = get_query_var( 'page_type' );
$pages = get_pages( array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'page_type',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $page_type,
    ),
  ),
) );

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
  // Output page title and content
  echo '<h2>' . $page->post_title . '</h2>';
  echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you register a taxonomy, you can choose the post type, to which the taxonomy should be registered. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

In your case this would be pages. This will affect all pages, because they are all of the type "page".

You can create another Post Type if you want to have that seperated from the pages.

With your function, you can add another type to be registered with the taxonomy. This register_taxonomy_for_object_type is to add an already registered taxonomy to an object type. We are taking about types, so it is correct behaviour that the taxonomy is now available for all pages.

I'm not quite sure if I got your question right... but if you want to assign a page template to a single specific page, you can just select the page template in the page attributes when editing a page in backend.

So you can either create another post type for pages where you only want to have a taxonomy, or you can make page templates to edit the template for single pages. Don't really know how this is meant in your question.

Maybe you can write more details what exactly you are trying to do and what problems you ran in.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I’ll try to explain why I need such functionality. I have custom post type called ‘Consultants’  and custom taxonomy ‘consultants_category’ (in fact this taxonomy – it’s categories for custom posts). With the help of ‘All import’ and ‘Advanced Custom Fields’ plugins I’m creating functionality to automatically create hundreds of ‘Consultants’ posts with different ‘consultants_category’ taxonomies assigned to each post. This all will be created automatically (xml file) without manual editing of separate post.

Comment: So we have custom posts and custom taxonomies attached to those posts.
Now we need to create separate pages for each custom taxonomy with the brief description of all custom posts which are linked to this taxonomy and with the list of all custom posts from this taxonomy (in fact - category). I need to create single php template for this page which will be used to create many-many other similar pages automatically. And on each such page we need to see list of custom post types from single taxonomy (category).

Comment: So my idea is to assign custom taxonomy to pages with specific php template (cuz we don’t need custom taxonomy to be assigned to all the rest regular pages) and once I will define that the page, which was created using custom php template, was assigned to specific category (custom taxonomy) – I will have on this page list of all posts assigned to the same taxonomy. 
Because we will have: hundreds of custom posts ‘Consultants’ and about 100 of pages to describe each category (custom taxonomy) - I need to make all this works automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your question and your comments, what you're looking for is an archive for that custom taxonomy:

> Rather than starting from a blank file, it is good practice to copy
>   the next file in the hierarchy, if it exists. If you’ve already
>   created an archive.php, make a copy called category.php and modify
>   that to suit your design needs. If you don’t have an archive.php file,
>   use a copy of your theme’s index.php as a starting point.

Taken from: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

So you'd basically take the `archive.php`, create a copy and name it `consultants_category.php` - then within that file layout and display the content how you need it to be displayed.  Use the `archive.php` file as a starting point and modify as needed.  When you do it this way it is pre-built to take your `consultants_category` taxonomy, identify which specific term in that taxonomy it needs to display, and then output the layout you've specified.

Comment: Thanks Tony! Yeah it's seems like a most reasonable answer in this case but the matter is I already created custom archive php template for this custom post type and it's already in use with the specific design:) I need to separate pages which will be created based on archive template and pages which will be created on 'page-consultants.php' template. I found finally solution for my case - on ACF plugin we can assign custom taxonomy to the specific page template and it's finally works! But I still don't know how to recreate it using php so I'm open to suggestions.